# chrome executeScript with file doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that I'm building using Angular 11, In one of my components, when an user clicks a button it will call the function `activate()`, which does the following

```
  activate(): void {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0]?.id, {file: 'content.js'}, () => {
          console.log('received');
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

My **content.js** (.ts, really), file has this for now, but it's intended to have plenty of lines of code since I want to do a lot of things with it

```
console.log('It works');
```

The problem is that `executeScript` isn't having any effect, I don't get the `console.log('It works')` in neither console (neither background and the page's console)

Here's my manifest, just in case

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "runtime.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

This is where I have my `content.ts` script

[image]

PS: I built the Chrome extension using this tutorial: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575

Notes:

1. I don't want the script to be executing all the time, I want it to start executing it after the user triggers certain event from the popup (hence the onMessage listener)
2. I don't get any error message but I get this warning and the test script doesn't do anything: `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hhniopibbnlahldmgpcfghgmcejcaeea/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` I don't get this error when I use `{code: }` instead of file but I can't use code

Comment: The `activeTab` permission can only be used in a listener for some user action. Move executeScript call to the popup (index.html) inside some click listener. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm wouldn't moving my `executeScript` away from my background script stop its execution when I close the popup? because I don't want that, I want that, once the user clicks a button in my popup execute that script even if the user closes the popup.

Comment: When you call executeScript it injects the file/code into the tab and that injected code runs regardless of whether the popup is open or not.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh, nice, I didn't know that, I'll try that out

Comment: @wOxxOm it still does nothing

Comment: I guess you've used it incorrectly. I can't help further without seeing the new code. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu and see what happens.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have edited my question to clarify from where I'm calling the method and where do I have my `content.ts` file

Comment: Assuming `activate` method is actually invoked from a click event listener and you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page I don't see any obvious problems so you'll have to debug it: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu, set breakpoints, see what happens.

Comment: @wOxxOm, well, apparently it can't read my file. The component is in root/src/app/extension/menu/menu.component.ts, while my content.ts script is in root, hence I tried to do `{file: '../../../../content.js'}` but it doesn't work

Comment: The source path doesn't matter here. You should use the real path in the compiled output e.g. `'/content.js'`. Look in the output directory using a file manager and see where your content.js is.

Comment: It appears nowhere

Comment: Then you need to add it to the config of your compiler (e.g. webpack).

Comment: My `content.js` script appears in my `dist` folder, but it doesn't appear in the file manager on Chrome, is there any reason for that? Do I have to change my manifest or something?

Comment: I don't know what "file manager on Chrome" is. Use a proper file manager that shows the actual contents of the directory.

Comment: I click inspect element on my popup and then go to the "Sources" tab

Comment: It's a devtools inspector, not a file manager, and it shows the files inside the popup page. The popup page is not related to the actual directory or to the web page. Use a real file manager to verify the real path of content.js and use it in executeScript. Then it will appear in devtools of the web page in "Content scripts" section of devtools.